# При попытке доступа к значению контролла пишет 'ApplicationWindow' object has no attribute 'pTextEdit'

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, matplotlib

При нажатии на кнопку хочу брать значение из полей `QLineEdit`, но скрипт у меня ругается:

```
AttributeError: 'ApplicationWindow' object has no attribute 'pTextEdit'
```

Вот листинг

```
class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def buttonClicked(self):

        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')
        self.show_plot(self.plt, self.pTextEdit.text(),self.qTextEdit.text()) #


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        pTextEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        qTextEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        
        btn1 = QPushButton("Запуск",self)

        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)
        
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)
        static_canvas = FigureCanvas(Figure(figsize=(5, 3)))
        
        layout.addWidget(static_canvas)
        layout.addWidget(btn1)

        
        layout.addWidget(pTextEdit)
        layout.addWidget(qTextEdit)

        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(static_canvas, self))
        self.plt = static_canvas.figure.subplots()
        self.plt.grid(True)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        w = 900; h = 600
    
        qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
        if not qapp:
            qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        app = ApplicationWindow()
        app.resize(w, h)
        app.show()
        app.activateWindow()
        app.raise_()
        qapp.exec_()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar   
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class ApplicationWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._main = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self._main)

        self.pTextEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)              # + self.
        self.qTextEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)              # + self.

        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Запуск",self)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.buttonClicked)

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 3))
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.grid(True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.addToolBar(NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self))

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self._main)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)    
        layout.addWidget(btn1)
        layout.addWidget(self.pTextEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.qTextEdit)

    def buttonClicked(self):
        sender = self.sender()
        self.statusBar().showMessage(sender.text() + ' was pressed')
        self.plot = self.axes.plot(float(self.pTextEdit.text()), float(self.qTextEdit.text()), 'o')
        self.axes.figure.canvas.draw()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    w = 900; h = 600

    qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    if not qapp:
        qapp = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app = ApplicationWindow()
    app.resize(w, h)
    app.show()
    app.activateWindow()
    app.raise_()
    qapp.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]