# Графики matplotlib в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, график

Только начал изучать построение графиков *matplotlib* в *Python* и не понимаю в чем проблема.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(1, 50, 1)
TTT = 100 + 4*a + 0.25*a*a
FFF = 100 + a*0
VVV = 4*a + 0,25*a*a

plt.plot(a, TTT)
plt.plot(a, FFF)
plt.plot(a, VVV)

plt.show()
```

Выводится такая ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Кирилл/Desktop/График.py", line 14, in <module>
    plt.plot(a, VVV)
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3019, in plot
    return gca().plot(
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 1605, in plot
    lines = [*self._get_lines(*args, data=data, **kwargs)]
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 315, in __call__
    yield from self._plot_args(this, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Кирилл\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 501, in _plot_args
    raise ValueError(f"x and y must have same first dimension, but "
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (49,) and (2, 49)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в опечатке. Замените **`VVV = 4*a + 0,25*a*a`** на **`VVV = 4*a + 0.25*a*a`** 
--------------------------------------------------> ^

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.arange(1, 50, 1)

TTT = 100 + 4*a + 0.25*a*a
FFF = 100 + a*0

#VVV = 4*a + 0,25*a*a
VVV = 4*a + 0.25*a*a                   # +++

plt.plot(a, TTT)
plt.plot(a, FFF)
plt.plot(a, VVV)

plt.show()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ого, спасибо)))

Comment: А можно каким-нибудь простым способом организовать ввод аргументов функции с клавиатуры? То есть не прописывать их заранее в самом коде

Comment: @Кирилл вот как это может выглядеть с использованием PyQt5 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247551 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1214761 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1126653 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1289435/ , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1117324 и т.д.

Comment: Питоновские кортежи очень удобны, но и очень коварны. Возникают внезапно ))